# Command which shows the most cpu intensive processes running on my system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command

I also want to kill processes which are not running on my kernel, as my system is getting slow.  Kindly assist.  Using Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your system is slow, focus on the top memory/cpu consumers and to do that use

```
$ top
```

to see which processes are the slowest.

You can then type k (for kill) and then the process you want to kill.  Use 15 for a soft-kill and 9 for a hard-kill if the softkill doesn't work.

You can type q to quit.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the total number of running processes with

```
$ ps aux | wc -l
```

As for killing processes, you need to be careful with that. However, using `top` or `ps` and providing the needed options (see the `man` pages) you can list processes run by specific users/belonging to specific groups.